# Create a maven webapp project using the eclipse kelper, I got an eclipse error

Tags: eclipse, maven, web-applications, archetypes

I have a problem, use Eclipse-jee-kelper to create Maven Project, my step is new/Maven Project/maven-archetype-webapp/naming/finish, I got a Failed to create project "test" error, as follows: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.1.1

My environment is: Windows 7 64bit, JDK 1.7, eclipse Jee kelper, Maven 3.1.1
This may be a stupid question, but has been entangled me all morning.
Kindly advise!
Thanks in advance!

---

I have to close this problem, because I found the answer from
[Spring's Forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/120244-while-creating-a-new-project-using-spring-template-project-i-am-getting-error)

Comment: Cool, thx for the link to the solution!

Answer (score 3):

The same error appears to me. I solved it by updating maven and checking the option "Force update of Snapshots/Releases" in Eclipse. this clears all errors. 
So right click on project -> Maven -> update project, then check the above option -> Ok.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:
1. Windows-->Preferences-->maven--> user settings-->add 
your maven directory/conf/ settings.XML   -->apply.
2. Next , installations -->add  -->your maven directory -->apply
After the two steps, maven test, or maven update project success.